Remove /api from swagger.json path in Azure Function out of process model
I have one endpoint defined with the following route:
/api/{id}

This interferes with the standard swagger.json path, that ends up being
/api/swagger.json

I wan to configure all swagger URLS so they don't have the /api prefix, alternatively have /docs instead of /api.
I have tried:
Servers = new List<OpenApiServer>() {new OpenApiServer()
{
     Url = "https://localhost:7071/docs",
     Description = "Localhost"
}

as well as proxies.json and local.settings.json settings. Nothing seems to bite.
Each azure function we have is centered around a specific domain model root. Hence we get a route like this:
GET /Api/{Id}

This also allows us to have a routePrefix in API Manager that adds a domain specific prefix, without the route turning wonky like /Users/Users/{Id}
This GET breaks the default swagger.json, because swagger.json is treated like {Id} in the GET entity path and this translates poorly to int or Guid.
GET /Api/Swagger.json

Hence I want to change swaggers default URLs so we get
GET /Api/{Id}
GET /Docs/Swagger.json

This also serves to separate the API from the documentation, making the urls slightly cleaner (in my mind). However the priority is to get Swagger.json to work, without having to alter the path to my existing API's.
Running .net 8 out of process azure function with C#

Can you share the function which you have tried?

Can you please share more details about the issue?

Added some more information now

To modify the route prefix of Azure functions from /api to /docs,  use below code in host.json to modify the default route:
host.json:
 "extensions": {
   "http": {
     "routePrefix": "docs"
   }

I have created a .NET 8.0 isolated Azure function.
host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "docs"
    }
  }
}


Able to change the route from /api to /docs:

[2024-06-12T10:19:37.311Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 15132) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-06-12T10:19:37.420Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7228/docs/docs

        RenderOAuth2Redirect: [GET] http://localhost:7228/docs/oauth2-redirect.html

        RenderOpenApiDocument: [GET] http://localhost:7228/docs/openapi/{version}.{extension}

        RenderSwaggerDocument: [GET] http://localhost:7228/docs/swagger.{extension}

        RenderSwaggerUI: [GET] http://localhost:7228/docs/swagger/ui

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-06-12T10:19:42.631Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-06-12T10:23:12.003Z] Executing 'Functions.RenderSwaggerUI' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=eb793924-150b-4294-aadb-414500aa463c)
[2024-06-12T10:23:12.442Z] SwaggerUI page was requested.
[2024-06-12T10:23:12.977Z] Executed 'Functions.RenderSwaggerUI' (Succeeded, Id=eb793924-150b-4294-aadb-414500aa463c, Duration=996ms)
[2024-06-12T10:23:13.210Z] Executing 'Functions.RenderSwaggerDocument' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=912d4c63-3749-4033-8021-ab3f7b37a561)
[2024-06-12T10:23:13.251Z] swagger.json was requested.
[2024-06-12T10:23:14.458Z] Executed 'Functions.RenderSwaggerDocument' (Succeeded, Id=912d4c63-3749-4033-8021-ab3f7b37a561, Duration=1[2024-06-12T10:23:24.898Z] Executing 'Functions.RenderSwaggerDocument' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=50fb5708-b6a8-442e-aafb-218fa3869a41)
[2024-06-12T10:23:24.911Z] swagger.json was requested.
[2024-06-12T10:23:25.125Z] Executed 'Functions.RenderSwaggerDocument' (Succeeded, Id=50fb5708-b6a8-442e-aafb-218fa3869a41, Duration=226ms)




Thank you for this answer, however, this affects all API's in the project and not just the swagger ones.
We have a route GET /api/{Id} - this route breaks the Swagger endpoint. Hence i need to change just the swagger api so we get:
GET /api/{Id} <--- fetches entity
GET /docs/swagger.json <-- fetches swagger docs
